# Modular Routes in Express

Tags: node.js, express

I would like to separate routes into several different files using `module.exports`.

Here is a very simple file:

```
// server/routes.js
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index/index');
  });
}
```

How can I import this into my entry point file? I have this so far...

```
var routes = require('./server/routes');
// ...
// try to import routes instead
app = routes(app);
```

Which causes my server to crash:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'listen' of undefined`

UPDATE: Here's the entire entry file

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var colors = require('colors');
var moment = require('moment');
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
var routes = require('./server/routes');

// set port
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

// set templating engine
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'ApplicationLayout', extname: ".hbs"}));
app.set('view engine', ".hbs");

// try to import routes instead
//app = routes(app);

// launch server
app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log(
    colors.rainbow('-------------------\n')
    + "App running on port: "
    + colors.red.underline(app.get('port'))
    + " "
    + colors.blue(moment().format('h:mm:ss a'))
    + colors.rainbow('\n-------------------')
  );
});
```

Comment: show place where you call method listen, pls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing something strange here `app = routes(app)` since your `function(app)` returns nothing.

Try simply:

```
routes(app);
```

`app` is an object reference (not a copy of the object), so whatever you do with it inside functions will immediately take effect.

P.S.

You could do it the way your wrote, but in that case `function(app)` should return `app`:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index/index');
  });
  return app;
}
```